# Power Query Custom Column Formula

Tags: dax, powerquery, m

I am trying to aggregate data brought in via power query and add a custom column. Essentially, I want to count all the first non-zero months in the data feed by group and report that count in a separate column.

For an example, this is what the input data looks like:

| Index | UNIQUEID | PRMS Reserves Category | PRMS Reserves Sub Category | Date | Gross Oil Well Head Volume (MBBL) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 36 | INPTegrxW4xbF6 | probable | undeveloped | 6/1/2027 | 0 |
| 36 | INPTegrxW4xbF6 | probable | undeveloped | 7/1/2027 | 0 |
| 36 | INPTegrxW4xbF6 | probable | undeveloped | 8/1/2027 | 0 |
| 36 | INPTegrxW4xbF6 | probable | undeveloped | 9/1/2027 | 14 |
| 36 | INPTegrxW4xbF6 | probable | undeveloped | 10/1/2027 | 24 |
| 36 | INPTegrxW4xbF6 | probable | undeveloped | 11/1/2027 | 27 |
| 37 | INPTegrxW4xbF7 | probable | undeveloped | 6/1/2027 | 0 |
| 37 | INPTegrxW4xbF7 | probable | undeveloped | 7/1/2027 | 0 |
| 37 | INPTegrxW4xbF7 | probable | undeveloped | 8/1/2027 | 0 |
| 37 | INPTegrxW4xbF7 | probable | undeveloped | 9/1/2027 | 14 |
| 37 | INPTegrxW4xbF7 | probable | undeveloped | 10/1/2027 | 24 |
| 37 | INPTegrxW4xbF7 | probable | undeveloped | 11/1/2027 | 27 |
| 38 | INPTegrxW4xbF8 | probable | undeveloped | 6/1/2027 | 0 |
| 38 | INPTegrxW4xbF8 | probable | undeveloped | 7/1/2027 | 0 |
| 38 | INPTegrxW4xbF8 | probable | undeveloped | 8/1/2027 | 0 |
| 38 | INPTegrxW4xbF8 | probable | undeveloped | 9/1/2027 | 14 |
| 38 | INPTegrxW4xbF8 | probable | undeveloped | 10/1/2027 | 24 |
| 38 | INPTegrxW4xbF8 | probable | undeveloped | 11/1/2027 | 27 |
| 39 | INPTegrxW4xbF9 | proved | undeveloped | 5/1/2027 | 0 |
| 39 | INPTegrxW4xbF9 | proved | undeveloped | 6/1/2027 | 0 |
| 39 | INPTegrxW4xbF9 | proved | undeveloped | 7/1/2027 | 0 |
| 39 | INPTegrxW4xbF9 | proved | undeveloped | 8/1/2027 | 14 |
| 39 | INPTegrxW4xbF9 | proved | undeveloped | 9/1/2027 | 24 |
| 39 | INPTegrxW4xbF9 | proved | undeveloped | 10/1/2027 | 27 |

and I would like the final query to look like this:

| PRMS Reserves Category | PRMS Reserves Sub Category | Date | Sum of Gross Oil | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| probable | undeveloped | 6/1/2027 | 0 | 0 |
| probable | undeveloped | 7/1/2027 | 0 | 0 |
| probable | undeveloped | 8/1/2027 | 0 | 0 |
| probable | undeveloped | 9/1/2027 | 42 | 3 |
| probable | undeveloped | 10/1/2027 | 72 | 0 |
| probable | undeveloped | 11/1/2027 | 81 | 0 |
| proved | undeveloped | 5/1/2027 | 0 | 0 |
| proved | undeveloped | 6/1/2027 | 0 | 0 |
| proved | undeveloped | 7/1/2027 | 0 | 0 |
| proved | undeveloped | 8/1/2027 | 14 | 1 |
| proved | undeveloped | 9/1/2027 | 24 | 0 |
| proved | undeveloped | 10/1/2027 | 27 | 0 |

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to write the function in power query's custom column?

Comment: Since all your dates **are** at the first of the month, just group by `Date` &  `PMRS Reserves Category`, and for aggregation do a `SUM` of the `Gross Oil Wellhead Volume`.

Comment: Thank you -- The Sum of Gross Oil is straightforward. Counting the first non-zero Gross Oil and counting those by group is where I was having trouble.

Comment: Not sure of the logic you are using.  What would you expect for output given Index 36,37,38 for 10/1/2027.  There are three rows, each with a Volume of 24.  In your output table you show 72 for the volume and 0 for the Count.  But for 9/1/2027 (same rows Index = 36,37,38) you show 3 for the count

Comment: That's right. 9/1/2027 have three records that are the first non-zero entry in `probable` `undeveloped`. 10/1/2027 has three non-zero records in that group, but they are the second (and not first) non-zero elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to calculate the minimal date `MinDate` for each category combination and then check if `Date = MinDate`

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("pZGxCoMwFEX/JbNgklqT/EChS+lQ6CAODYYuUkWo+PlN62DNe8vV7SVwznBPVYlDKTJxvlxv4TlM92Lyp+9HP3T+4dsQz/erCWNouz408VXmKtdSm3hKUWcwb3bydifvFl4VWwRKLga9zaD+DGY2mNRgsAgYTyNgPI2A8UwETMBFAA1MBJsaLBYB42kEjKcRMJ6JgAm4CKCBieBSg5sN449Y80cyAULTgAhN8yG0peMjuKPLI/iqXNy9/gA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Index = _t, UNIQUEID = _t, #"PRMS Reserves Category" = _t, #"PRMS Reserves Sub Category" = _t, Date = _t, #"Gross Oil Well Head Volume (MBBL)" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Index", Int64.Type}, {"UNIQUEID", type text}, {"PRMS Reserves Category", type text}, {"PRMS Reserves Sub Category", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"Gross Oil Well Head Volume (MBBL)", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([#"Gross Oil Well Head Volume (MBBL)"] <> 0)),
    #"Grouped Category" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"PRMS Reserves Category", "PRMS Reserves Sub Category"}, {{"MinDate", each List.Min([Date]), type nullable date}}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type", {"PRMS Reserves Category", "PRMS Reserves Sub Category"}, #"Grouped Category", {"PRMS Reserves Category", "PRMS Reserves Sub Category"}, "Grouped Rows", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Grouped Rows" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Grouped Rows", {"MinDate"}, {"MinDate"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Grouped Rows", "Custom", each if [Date] = [MinDate] then 1 else 0, Int64.Type),
    #"Grouped Category and Date" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"PRMS Reserves Category", "PRMS Reserves Sub Category", "Date"}, {{"Gross", each List.Sum([#"Gross Oil Well Head Volume (MBBL)"]), type nullable number}, {"Count", each List.Sum([Custom]), type number}})
in
    #"Grouped Category and Date"
```

This computes the `MinDate` in the `#"Grouped Category"` step by taking the min over the `Date` column after filtering out `0` values:

[image: Subquery screenshot]

Then it merges this `MinDate` column back into the original table and adds a custom column using the logic `if [Date] = [MinDate] then 1 else 0`.

[image: Custom column screenshot]

The final step groups on the first three columns shown above, summing over Gross Oil and Custom.

[image: Final result screenshot]